# Google Play Warning: APK will result on fewer types of devices

Tags: android, google-play, apk

When releasing a new beta to Play Store, this is the warning that I receive:

```
Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices.
```

And it show that it is due to localization changes:

[image]

[image]

It's an odd warning since I don't have the translations for the languages under *differentiating* and I haven't made changes to the existing translations either. I know that Google Play console had UI and PLR issues last week but don't know if this is one of the issues. Just wondering why these differences could be down from 31 to only 2.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same warning when I published an update last week. My app has zero translations. I don't think it's anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Include an image snippet of the google play console informing you that it's due to location changes. From my own experience, you've probably added something in your Manifest (most likely a `<uses-feature>` tag) that has caused the app to work on fewer devices.